# Get lat/lng inside an irregular shape polygon

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using this function to get centroid of an irregular shape polygon however when the polygon is an L shape the point is outside.

```
function get_polygon_centroid(pts) {
    var first = pts[0], last = pts[pts.length-1];
    if (first.x != last.x || first.y != last.y) pts.push(first);
        var twicearea=0,
        x=0, y=0,
        nPts = pts.length,
        p1, p2, f;
        for ( var i=0, j=nPts-1 ; i<nPts ; j=i++ ) {
            p1 = pts[i]; p2 = pts[j];
            f = p1.x*p2.y - p2.x*p1.y;
            twicearea += f;          
            x += ( p1.x + p2.x ) * f;
            y += ( p1.y + p2.y ) * f;
        }
        f = twicearea * 3;
    return { x:x/f, y:y/f };
}
```

My points are:

```
(-37.81418,145.13025000000002),
(-37.814330000000005,145.13022),
(-37.813970000000005,145.12727),
(-37.813750000000006,145.12543000000002),
(-37.813680000000005,145.12478000000002),
(-37.81152,145.12517000000003),
(-37.809380000000004,145.12558),
(-37.80951,145.12675000000002),
(-37.80953,145.12685000000002),
(-37.810590000000005,145.12667000000002),
(-37.812630000000006,145.12631000000002),
(-37.81275,145.12628),
(-37.81324,145.13026000000002),
(-37.81326,145.13044000000002),
(-37.81418,145.13025000000002)
```

I would like to get a point inside the polygon which is far enough off the boundary if possible.

Comment: Look at this link for a good example
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#polygons_complex_v3

Comment: try like this https://codepen.io/jhawes/pen/ujdgK

Comment: I don't understand what this is. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option:

1. find your centroid, if it is not inside the polygon

   - calculate all the points halfway between the calculated centroid and the vertices of the polygon
   - eliminate any that are not inside the polygon.

With your set of data, this results in 7 candidate points.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5gvw9rtc/2/)

[image: map with markers inside polygon]

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    paths: data
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: get_polygon_centroid(data)
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getLength(); i++) {
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      map: map,
      path: [marker.getPosition(), polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getAt(i)]
    });
    var length = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(polyline.getPath());
    var pt = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(marker.getPosition(), length / 2,
      google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(marker.getPosition(), polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getAt(i)));
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(pt, polygon)) {
      var candidateMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: pt,
        icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
      });
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function get_polygon_centroid(pts) {
  var first = pts[0],
    last = pts[pts.length - 1];
  if (first.lat != last.lat || first.lng != last.lng) pts.push(first);
  var twicearea = 0,
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    nPts = pts.length,
    p1, p2, f;
  for (var i = 0, j = nPts - 1; i < nPts; j = i++) {
    p1 = pts[i];
    p2 = pts[j];
    f = p1.lng * p2.lat - p2.lng * p1.lat;
    twicearea += f;
    x += (p1.lng + p2.lng) * f;
    y += (p1.lat + p2.lat) * f;
  }
  f = twicearea * 3;
  return {
    lng: x / f,
    lat: y / f
  };
}

var data = [{
  lat: -37.81418,
  lng: 145.13025000000002
}, {
  lat: -37.814330000000005,
  lng: 145.13022
}, {
  lat: -37.813970000000005,
  lng: 145.12727
}, {
  lat: -37.813750000000006,
  lng: 145.12543000000002
}, {
  lat: -37.813680000000005,
  lng: 145.12478000000002
}, {
  lat: -37.81152,
  lng: 145.12517000000003
}, {
  lat: -37.809380000000004,
  lng: 145.12558
}, {
  lat: -37.80951,
  lng: 145.12675000000002
}, {
  lat: -37.80953,
  lng: 145.12685000000002
}, {
  lat: -37.810590000000005,
  lng: 145.12667000000002
}, {
  lat: -37.812630000000006,
  lng: 145.12631000000002
}, {
  lat: -37.81275,
  lng: 145.12628
}, {
  lat: -37.81324,
  lng: 145.13026000000002
}, {
  lat: -37.81326,
  lng: 145.13044000000002
}, {
  lat: -37.81418,
  lng: 145.13025000000002
}]
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option:

- simplify your polygon using something like Douglas-Peucker (right now you have extra points that will generate lots of possible points)
- calculate all the points halfway between every unique set of non-adjacent vertices of the polygon
- eliminate any that are not inside the polygon.

With your set of data, this results in 5 candidate points.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5gvw9rtc/12/)

[image: map with markers inside polygon]

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var path = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng));
  }
  var simplifiedPath = GDouglasPeucker(path, 20);

  var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    map: map,
    paths: simplifiedPath
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: get_polygon_centroid(data)
  });
  // check each pair of non-adjacent points
  for (var i = 0; i < polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getLength() - 2; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 2; j < polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getLength(); j++) {
      var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
        map: map,
        path: [polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getAt(i), polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getAt(j)],
        strokeColor: 'blue'
      });
      var length = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeLength(polyline.getPath());
      var pt = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getAt(i), length / 2,
        google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getAt(i), polygon.getPaths().getAt(0).getAt(j)));
      console.log("[i=" + i + ",j=" + j + "] abs(diff)=" + Math.abs(i - j) + " coords:" + pt.toUrlValue(6));
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(pt, polygon) &&
        !google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge(pt, polygon, 10e-8)) {
        var candidateMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: pt,
          icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
          title: "[i=" + i + ",j=" + j + "] " + pt.toUrlValue(6)
        });
      } else polyline.setMap(null);
    }
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function get_polygon_centroid(pts) {
  var first = pts[0],
    last = pts[pts.length - 1];
  if (first.lat != last.lat || first.lng != last.lng) pts.push(first);
  var twicearea = 0,
    x = 0,
    y = 0,
    nPts = pts.length,
    p1, p2, f;
  for (var i = 0, j = nPts - 1; i < nPts; j = i++) {
    p1 = pts[i];
    p2 = pts[j];
    f = p1.lng * p2.lat - p2.lng * p1.lat;
    twicearea += f;
    x += (p1.lng + p2.lng) * f;
    y += (p1.lat + p2.lat) * f;
  }
  f = twicearea * 3;
  return {
    lng: x / f,
    lat: y / f
  };
}

var data = [{
    lat: -37.81418,
    lng: 145.13025000000002
  }, {
    lat: -37.814330000000005,
    lng: 145.13022
  }, {
    lat: -37.813970000000005,
    lng: 145.12727
  }, {
    lat: -37.813750000000006,
    lng: 145.12543000000002
  }, {
    lat: -37.813680000000005,
    lng: 145.12478000000002
  }, {
    lat: -37.81152,
    lng: 145.12517000000003
  }, {
    lat: -37.809380000000004,
    lng: 145.12558
  }, {
    lat: -37.80951,
    lng: 145.12675000000002
  }, {
    lat: -37.80953,
    lng: 145.12685000000002
  }, {
    lat: -37.810590000000005,
    lng: 145.12667000000002
  }, {
    lat: -37.812630000000006,
    lng: 145.12631000000002
  }, {
    lat: -37.81275,
    lng: 145.12628
  }, {
    lat: -37.81324,
    lng: 145.13026000000002
  }, {
    lat: -37.81326,
    lng: 145.13044000000002
  }, {
    lat: -37.81418,
    lng: 145.13025000000002
  }]
  /* Stack-based Douglas Peucker line simplification routine 
     returned is a reduced GLatLng array 
     After code by  Dr. Gary J. Robinson,
     Environmental Systems Science Centre,
     University of Reading, Reading, UK
  */

function GDouglasPeucker(source, kink)
  /* source[] Input coordinates in GLatLngs  */
  /* kink in metres, kinks above this depth kept  */
  /* kink depth is the height of the triangle abc where a-b and b-c are two consecutive line segments */
  {
    var n_source, n_stack, n_dest, start, end, i, sig;
    var dev_sqr, max_dev_sqr, band_sqr;
    var x12, y12, d12, x13, y13, d13, x23, y23, d23;
    var F = ((Math.PI / 180.0) * 0.5);
    var index = new Array(); /* aray of indexes of source points to include in the reduced line */
    var sig_start = new Array(); /* indices of start & end of working section */
    var sig_end = new Array();

    /* check for simple cases */

    if (source.length < 3)
      return (source); /* one or two points */

    /* more complex case. initialize stack */

    n_source = source.length;
    band_sqr = kink * 360.0 / (2.0 * Math.PI * 6378137.0); /* Now in degrees */
    band_sqr *= band_sqr;
    n_dest = 0;
    sig_start[0] = 0;
    sig_end[0] = n_source - 1;
    n_stack = 1;

    /* while the stack is not empty  ... */
    while (n_stack > 0) {

      /* ... pop the top-most entries off the stacks */

      start = sig_start[n_stack - 1];
      end = sig_end[n_stack - 1];
      n_stack--;

      if ((end - start) > 1) { /* any intermediate points ? */

        /* ... yes, so find most deviant intermediate point to
               either side of line joining start & end points */

        x12 = (source[end].lng() - source[start].lng());
        y12 = (source[end].lat() - source[start].lat());
        if (Math.abs(x12) > 180.0)
          x12 = 360.0 - Math.abs(x12);
        x12 *= Math.cos(F * (source[end].lat() + source[start].lat())); /* use avg lat to reduce lng */
        d12 = (x12 * x12) + (y12 * y12);

        for (i = start + 1, sig = start, max_dev_sqr = -1.0; i < end; i++) {

          x13 = (source[i].lng() - source[start].lng());
          y13 = (source[i].lat() - source[start].lat());
          if (Math.abs(x13) > 180.0)
            x13 = 360.0 - Math.abs(x13);
          x13 *= Math.cos(F * (source[i].lat() + source[start].lat()));
          d13 = (x13 * x13) + (y13 * y13);

          x23 = (source[i].lng() - source[end].lng());
          y23 = (source[i].lat() - source[end].lat());
          if (Math.abs(x23) > 180.0)
            x23 = 360.0 - Math.abs(x23);
          x23 *= Math.cos(F * (source[i].lat() + source[end].lat()));
          d23 = (x23 * x23) + (y23 * y23);

          if (d13 >= (d12 + d23))
            dev_sqr = d23;
          else if (d23 >= (d12 + d13))
            dev_sqr = d13;
          else
            dev_sqr = (x13 * y12 - y13 * x12) * (x13 * y12 - y13 * x12) / d12; // solve triangle

          if (dev_sqr > max_dev_sqr) {
            sig = i;
            max_dev_sqr = dev_sqr;
          }
        }

        if (max_dev_sqr < band_sqr) { /* is there a sig. intermediate point ? */
          /* ... no, so transfer current start point */
          index[n_dest] = start;
          n_dest++;
        } else {
          /* ... yes, so push two sub-sections on stack for further processing */
          n_stack++;
          sig_start[n_stack - 1] = sig;
          sig_end[n_stack - 1] = end;
          n_stack++;
          sig_start[n_stack - 1] = start;
          sig_end[n_stack - 1] = sig;
        }
      } else {
        /* ... no intermediate points, so transfer current start point */
        index[n_dest] = start;
        n_dest++;
      }
    }

    /* transfer last point */
    index[n_dest] = n_source - 1;
    n_dest++;

    /* make return array */
    var r = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < n_dest; i++)
      r.push(source[index[i]]);
    return r;

  }
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```